# when I am trying to create a log_in function?Why I have error Error(3,10): PLS-00215: String length constraints must be in range (1 .. 32767)

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to create a function to verify log_in by return 0(zero) if the login failed, or 1(one) if the login was successful by matching cust_id and Passwd as parametrars and I have two questions:

1. Why I get error bad bind p_cust_id?
2. How to return 0 when it fail?

.

```
create or replace function log_in
( 
   p_cust_id varchar2, 
   p_paswd varchar2
) return number
as p_all varchar2;    
begin     
  select cust_id,passwd
  into p_all
  from customer
  where cust_id=p_cust_id and passwd=p_paswd;

  return 1;
end;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you are trying to select 2 column but into 1 variable. this can't be possible. check my fix below

```
select cust_id,passwd
into variable1, variable2
from customer
where cust_id=p_cust_id and passwd=p_paswd;
```

for your second requirement, you need to add below line before end.

```
EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  return 0;
END;
```

**EDIT**

Your procedure can also be rewritten as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION LOG_IN
( 
   P_CUST_ID VARCHAR2, 
   P_PASWD VARCHAR2
) RETURN NUMBER
AS P_COUNT NUMBER;    
BEGIN     
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO P_COUNT
  FROM CUSTOMER
  WHERE CUST_ID=P_CUST_ID AND PASSWD=P_PASWD;

  IF (P_COUNT > 0)
    RETURN 1;
  END IF;

  RETURN 0;
END;
```

Comment: If you believe that this answer is helpfull, please consider to upvote :)